# Show Compiler Generated Code for Closure

Tags: c#, closures

I have created a small Test-Class:

```
public delegate int Adder();

class Example {
    static Adder CreateAdder() {
        int x = 0;
        return delegate {
            x++;
            return x;
        };
    }

    public static void Test() {
        Adder add = CreateAdder();
        Console.WriteLine(add());
        Console.WriteLine(add());
        Console.WriteLine(add());
    }
}
```

x is a Closure-Variable. Now, I can look with Reflector, that the compiler generates the following helper-class:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0 {
   public int x;
   internal int <CreateAdder>b__0() {
       int x = this.x;
       this.x = x + 1;
       return this.x;
   }
}
```

But I cannot see, how this Helper-Class will be used in the Test-Method. Is there a possibility to show the Test-Method with using of the Helper-Class?

Comment: You can use ILDASM or JetBrain's dotPeek to decompile your assembly and see what's going on in `Test()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the exciting part is not in `Test()`. Because `Test()` simply calls a delegate (`add`).

```
// decompiled code is the same as original source
public static void Test()
{
  Adder add = Example.CreateAdder();
  Console.WriteLine(add());
  Console.WriteLine(add());
  Console.WriteLine(add());
}
```

The compiler-generated class is used in `CreateAdder()`:

```
private static Adder CreateAdder()
{
  Example.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 cDisplayClass00 = new Example.<>c__DisplayClass0_0();
  cDisplayClass00.x = 0;
  return new Adder((object) cDisplayClass00, __methodptr(<CreateAdder>b__0));
}
```

So to create the delegate, an object of the compiler-generated class is instantiated. And the delegate targets this object and it's `<CreateAdder>b__0` method (which represents what you did in your anonymous method).

---

I used [JetBrain's dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to decompile it. [ILDASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) is an alternative by Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: Did you see the compiler-generated class in dotPeek? I do not :-(

Comment: ["Click Turn Compiler-generated Code On/Off ThemedIcon ShowCompilerCode Screen Gray on the toolbar."](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/Viewing_Compiler_Generated_Code.html)